# Object instance assigned in PHPUnit setUp function becomes non-object in test function

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, fatal-error

I've got a class, DummyClass, which stores a value when an object instance is created, using a constructor:

```
class DummyClass
{
    private $foo = '';

    function __construct($foobar)
    {
        $this->foo = $foobar;
    }

    public function getFoo() { return $foo; }
}
```

Then I've got a test class, DummyTest, which uses setUp() to construct an instance of DummyClass. Then, in test__construct(), it asserts that its own property, $foo, and the variable returned from the DummyClass instance, are equal:

```
require_once 'DummyClass.php';

class DummyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $instance = NULL;
    public $foo;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $foo = 'bar';
        $this->instance = new DummyClass($foo);
    }

    public function test__construct()
    {
        $foobar = $instance->getFoo();
        $this->assertEquals($foobar, $foo);
    }

}
```

However, when I run the test in phpunit I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFoo() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\DummyTest.php on line 16

How come $instance isn't an object in test__construct(), and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: $foobar = $this->instance->getFoo(); NOT $foobar = $instance->getFoo();

Comment: and also not ' public function getFoo() { return $foo; }' but ' public function getFoo() { return $this->foo; }

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I also figured this out myself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access object of class using `this`. Check this,

```
public function test__construct()
{
    //$foobar = $instance->getFoo(); 
    $foobar = $this->instance->getFoo(); 
    $this->assertEquals($foobar, $foo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me make this test work. I didn't realize that I need to use $this-> both when storing properties, and accessing them.